# Custom Request. Валидация запроса. Сделать по принципу DRY

Tags: laravel, dry

У меня в кастомных запросах
есть такая отправка ответов запроса в каждом (Custom)Request

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(
            Json::validationFailed(['errors' => $validator->errors()])
        );
    }
```

На лицо типичное повторение кода. Как сделать по-нормальному? Чтобы это было где-то в одном месте?

Comment: Я вижу, что вы используете Validator напрямую. А вы знакомы со вторым способом проверки запроса через инкапсуляцию в специальный [класс запроса](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation)? Если не подходит, напишите больше кода, потому что по тому что есть, трудно понять где тут не соблюдение DRY.

Comment: Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос просто повесьте свой обработчик ошибок по верх ларовского

Comment: @TotalPusher вот и говорю, у меня множество кастомных реквестов, и в каждом из них этот код повторяется.

Comment: тогда используйте наследование или трейты. есть еще композиция, но она вряд ли подойтет, покажите каким образом вызывается failedValidation из кода